# How to Create jquery DataTable from angular $sce Generated Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datatables

I have written angular controller which takes data and generate HTML Table from It the generated table in displaying in the page
How i can apply jquery data table using that scope variable.
The variable contains the html form of table starting with

```
    <table id="planeTable">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

Following is the code of controller

```
$scope.GetPlaneData = function($window){

    $scope.tmp = this;
    planeapi.ReadAllPlanes.Init().then(function(data){
        $scope.tableResult = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.$apply();
            $scope.tableResult.toString().$window.DataTable();
            // ^^ APPLY DATA TABLE ON $SCOPE.TABLERESULT
        });

        },function(err){
        alert(err);
    });
        //$("#planeTable").$window.DataTable();
};
```

Comment: You want to fill your table with your data ?

Comment: actually the table with data is coming from server with all html table tag i want to apply datatable in it or paging that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dom Manipulations should not exist in controllers, services or anywhere else but in directives.
I decided to create directive for this table.